# How can i call a method on ES6 class outside it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I try to make a decorator for class and gain deeper understanding of how things work with es6 classes. So i stumbled upon a question — are there any way to access class internals from outside since can't invoke it as a function

Example: given following function transpiled by Babel:

```
function App() {
    (0, _classCallCheck3.default)(this, App);

    var _this = (0, _possibleConstructorReturn3.default)(this, (0, _getPrototypeOf2.default)(App).call(this));

    _this.returnState = _this.returnState.bind(_this);
    return _this;
  }
```

are there any ways to access the method returnState from outside?

Comment: What would you do with it? That method is an instance method, so "call a method on ES6 class" makes not much sense.

Comment: ES6 class syntax actually puts methods on the prototype so you can find any method on the prototype.  Are you asking about a class definition?  Or  an instance of a class?

Comment: Lets say this class holds some state i'm interested in.

Comment: The class or an instance? ES6 **does not** provide* facilities to have class members.

Comment: So if you have an instance - simply call `instance.returnState()`

Comment: Yeah, that kinda helps. Thank you!